# Create symbolic link for directory, symbolic link end up inside target

Tags: symlink

I know it's been asked [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux), but I followed the instruction  and cannot create the link. The symlink (`gradle-current`) always ends up inside the target (`gradle-2.7`)

```
cd ~
ln --symbolic -t /home/tung/gradle-2.7/  /home/tung/gradle-current/
```

or other version:

```
cd ~
ln --symbolic -t gradle-2.7  gradle-current
```

still no luck, any tip? Thanks

Comment: What is your desired end result?  The `-t` flag is working as it is supposed to, from what you say.  Where did you want the link to be and where did you want it to point?

Comment: I want the `gradle-current` link to point to `gradle 2.7` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-t` specifies a directory *in which to create* a symlink.  It doesn't specify a directory which is to be *targeted* by the symlink.

What you want is `ln -s gradle-2.7 gradle-current`.  This creates a symlink called "gradle-current" which points to "gradle-2.7".

In actual fact it doesn't matter whether gradle-2.7 is a directory or a file—the command is the same.

Actually, it doesn't matter if gradle-2.7 *exists* or not, the command is still the same for creating the symlink.  (The symlink won't *work* if the target doesn't exist, but it can still be created.  If the target is later created, the symlink will then operate without any additional work.)

Comment: the target does not even need to exist ... the command is the same

Comment: @Skaperen: Good point, I added that to my explanation.  :)